# How to rename a file using find command

Tags: command-line, find, mv

I am trying to rename a file using `find` command.

I am trying to rename file-a to file-10.

To do this I first tried below command:

```
sps@sps-Inspiron-N5110:~$ find ~ -type f -name test-a -exec mv test-10 '{}' ';'
mv: cannot stat `test-10': No such file or directory
sps@sps-Inspiron-N5110:~$
```

Then I tried below:

```
sps@sps-Inspiron-N5110:~$ find ~ -type f -name test-a -exec mv test-a test-10 '{}' ';'
mv: target `/home/sps/test-a' is not a directory
sps@sps-Inspiron-N5110:~$
```

Now I cant think how to do that with `find`. I am trying to do this with `find`, because I will have many directories with same filename, and I want to change all the `test-a` to `test-10` in one command. Anyone please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: Are all the files called exactly `test-a` (and intended to be renamed to `test-10`)? Or is your goal to search for files whose names end in `-a` (but may otherwise be anything) and rename them to end in `-10` instead?

Comment: @EliahKagan yes, the files are exactly test-a

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The syntax of `mv` is `mv <source> <target>`, so the final command that `find` executes should look like:

```
mv test-a test-10
```

So, the first guess would be try:

```
find ~ -type f -name test-a -exec mv {} test-10 \;
```

However, this will fail, since `{}` gets expanded to the full path and `mv` is still run in the current directory, resulting in all the files being moved to your current directory and getting overwritten. To avoid this, you can use `-execdir` so that `mv` gets executed in the directory where the file was found:

```
find ~ -type f -name test-a -execdir mv {} test-10 \;
```

Or, since the filename is always the same:

```
find ~ -type f -name test-a -execdir mv test-a test-10 \;
```

Comment: And another one bows deeply to Master Muru...  ;-)  (Upvoted!)